# Unsrestricted form to restricted form(CNF)

Tags: optimization, boolean, z3, n-queens, sat

I need to convert unrestricted Propositional formula into CNF and then into 3-SAT. I know Rewriting Rules for Translating Formulas into Conjunctive Normal Form

```
α ↔ β (¬α ∨ β) ∧ (¬β ∨ α) 
α → β ¬α ∨ β (4.2)
¬(α ∨ β) ¬α ∧ ¬β (4.3)
¬(α ∧ β) ¬α ∨ ¬β (4.4)
¬¬α α (4.5)
α ∨ (β ∧ γ) (α ∨ β) ∧ (α ∨ γ) (4.6)
(α ∧ β) ∨ γ (α ∨ γ) ∧ (β ∨ γ
```

But I don't understand how I find real life example about concept. Could you help about  implementation. I can't find real life example. Thank you.

Actually I try to show that unrestricted formulas can be converted into
restricted forms, and solution for both is the same. So I write any  unrestricted Propositional formula  Convert it into CNF and then into 3-SAT(by hand) by this way I can show similar result.
Thus I need  USAT-org and USAT-converted, where org is the
unrestricted formula, and converted is the formula in 3-CNF as an SMT syntax (SMT-LIB2 files)

Answer (score 0):

You can go about it one at a time. Let's take the second one, for instance:

```
α → β
```

becomes:

```
 ¬α ∨ β
```

In SMTLib, you'd prove the equivalence of these two expressions by asserting the negation of their equivalence and checking for `unsat`. The idea is that if the negation is unsatisfiable, then the equivalence must hold for all values.

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-logic QF_BV)
(declare-fun alpha () Bool)
(declare-fun beta  () Bool)

(define-fun lhs () Bool (=> alpha beta))
(define-fun rhs () Bool (or (not alpha) beta))

(assert (not (= lhs rhs)))
(check-sat)
```

This prints:

```
unsat
```

So, the above means the transformation is correct for arbitrary values of `alpha` and `beta`.

Using the same trick, you should prove each one of your transformations. Then it's a bit of meta-reasoning (or you can do manual induction yourself) to show that if you apply these transformations on all sub-formulas till they're all written away, you can convert arbitrary formulas to this form. Note that this last step cannot directly be done with an SMT solver as it needs induction; but you can either do a manual proof of use a proper theorem prover like Isabelle/ACL2/Hol/Lean etc.